# Efficiently estimating the area of an unknown number of regions given that one sample is enough to compute the area of a region

Tags: simulation, monte-carlo

(Apologies if the title may sound confusing - I'm not a native English speaker)

This problem is a (very coarse) simplification of a research project I've been working on. I hope my attempt at abstracting the technical details will make the core issues more understandable.

## The Problem

Let's say that my little nephew received a **really big** (n-dimensional) [coloring book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coloring_book#/media/File:Garfield_Goose_1953_book_at_home_in_castle.jpg) as a gift. Since he doesn't have any coloring pencils or
paint, so he asks me to buy some. Given the absurd size of the book (and that I'm kind of an 'Uncle Scrooge'), I ask my little nephew
to give me a precise estimate of how much paint he'll need. After a couple of hours, my nephew returns with a computer program $C(x)$ that, given a point $x$ in the book, computes:

- The *partition* of the coloring book (e.g. the goose's hat in the link above) that contains *x*. All partitions are unique and completely disjoint from each other;
- The *color* that he plans to paint that partition;
- The *exact amount of paint* needed to paint the partition.

$C(x)$ also has a "fast" mode, $C_f(x)$, that only returns the color for that partition, but it is an order of magnitude faster than the default mode.
Enumerating all partitions in the book is possible, but completely infeasible in general given the massive size of the search space. We also don't know how many regions are associated with each color. We can test, however, if a sample $x$ is inside of a specific partition $A$ very quickly.

Given all of the above, how would you estimate how much paint of a specific color (e.g. blue) you need to buy?

## Comments

The basic solution I've implemented is a basic Hit-or-Miss Monte Carlo, but I can't see how to use the information provided by $C(x)$ efficiently (i.e. how to avoid sampling in the regions where I know the exact answer). Maybe a fancier MC algorithm (MCMC & friends) could help?

## Extensions

- *Brightness*: $C(x)$ (in both modes) now also reports the brightness (in a continuous scale) of the pigment that should be used to paint
  the partition (e.g. "light blue"). How can I estimate what's the brightest "hue" for a certain color?

Comment: Do you know the total area of the book (in which case you only need to estimate the proportion of each colour)? Or is that also unknown?

Comment: Yes, the total area of the book (as well as size of each dimension) is known.

Comment: If you have visited a partition once, can you reuse the information? For instance, you sample $x$, compute $C(x)$ and find that $x\in A_1$ and get the color and volume of $A_1$. For a new point $y$, can you decide whether $y\in A_1$ without computing $C(y)$?

Comment: Yes, you can assume that there's a subroutine $T(A,x)$ that efficiently checks    if $x \in A$. I'll add this information.

Comment: capture-recapture and species richness come to mind as statistical techniques.